# Magento creates cache images of 0 KB

Tags: image, magento, caching

I'm Using Magento 1.8.0 with a template. All worked fine untill i transferd from shared to a new VPS.

When i want to add a product it wont show the product image on the frontend. It creates a file in the cache folder, only problem is, it is 0 KB. I have set all the permissions to 777 on the media folder, checked the GD libery. 
gd

- GD Support: enabled
- GD Version: bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
- FreeType Support: enabled
- FreeType Linkage: with freetype
- FreeType Version: 2.5.3
- GIF Read Support: enabled
- GIF Create Support: enabled
- JPEG Support: enabled
- libJPEG Version: 6b
- PNG Support: enabled
- libPNG Version: 1.2.51
- WBMP Support: enabled
- XBM Support: enabled

Anyone any ideas how to solve this? It drives me crazy!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I contact my VPS provider and the recompiled the PHP and JPG library!
There was an error in the provided VPS image.
After recompiling it worked! But maybe you have also to clear the cache after the compiling.